# Запомнить пред предыдущее значение в массиве php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть примерный массив

```
$arr = array(1,12,34,34,34,50,56,56,22);
```

Как можно определить при переборе массива будет ли следовать за текущим значением еще одно такое. Тоесть как бы нужно понять если элемент 1 в списке то делаем что-то, если таких элементов несколько (повторяющиеся) то делаем только на последнем.
Пробовал сделать так

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
if(isset($old_value) && $old_value == $arr[$i]) { 
    // если есть совпадение с предыдущим значением
    // то группируем данные
} else {
    // иначе добавляем в базу
}
$old_value = $arr[$i];
}
```

Только здесь проблема в том что при переборе первое повторяющееся число будет попадать в условие где данные добавляются в базу

Comment: сделать ассоциативный массив, где ключ - элемент с массива вашего, значение - его индекс. Идете по вашему массиву и записываете актуальный индекс. В конце пройдитесь по созданному массиву, где значения будут последние индексы. Если элемент в массиве существует, просто перезапишите его индекс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
   // если не последний и равен следующему
   if(isset($arr[$i+1]) and ($arr[$i+1] == $arr[$i])) { 
      // то группируем данные
   } 
   else {
      // иначе добавляем в базу
   }
 }
```

Comment: То что нужно, гениально и просто))

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно создавать никаких дополнительных переменных чтобы это узнать.

```
$arr = array(1,12,34,34,34,50,56,56,22);

for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
    if (isset($arr[$i+1])&&$arr[$i]!=$arr[$i+1]){
        echo 'следующие значения не повторяются у эл-тов с индексом: '.$i.PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'следующие значения повторяются у эл-тов с индексом:'.$i.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось намного проще, вот код

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
if(isset($old_value) && $old_value == $arr[$i]) { 
    // если есть совпадение с предыдущим значением
    // то групирем данные
} else {
    // иначе добавляем в базу
}
if($i > 1) $older_value = $old_value;
$old_value = $arr[$i];
}
```

Нужно всего лишь перед присваиванием предыдущего значения записать в переменную данные $old_vale;

Answer (score 0):

> нужно понять если элемент 1 в списке то делаем что-то, если таких элементов несколько (повторяющиеся) то делаем только на последнем

Если всё обстоит именно так, то можно использовать [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php)

```
$uniqItems = array_unique($arr);
foreach ($uniqItems as $item) {
    // делаем что-то
}
```